# Selecting Video player in HTML

Tags: html

I have a .avi file .I want to play it using a vlc media player or quicktime in  a webpage(HTML).Any idea how to do this?
By default it opens up in windows media player and that is not able to open the file

Comment: Are you trying to build a web page and embed video in it?

Comment: Yes...I am building a webpage using GWT and I want a particular file to be played with a particular player .Is there a way to do it ?Video is stored on my machine .Currently i do :-                                                                                                                                            

Panel.add(new HTML("<embed src=\"XYZ.avi\" width=\"367\" height=\"275\" "+controller=\"true\" ShowStatusBar=\"true\"   ShowControls=\"true\""+"/>")) ;

Answer (score 0):

Today you can use tag `<video>` for it ;)

It is not necessary to use any video player for playing video on webpage.